# Picture a graph without words

Tags: mathematics, visual, real

You may have played/sung/heard a
song without words
in [concert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcw-MR6o74k),
in [choir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLTqb-fMHIA),
and in a
Sushi restaurant.
Who hasn’t?!

Well here is a picture without words, only axes:

[image]

And here it is without JPG-encodingly unavoidable enhancements:

[image]

> Bring this gallery to life by reproducing any aspect of the above.

(Truly, I’m still trying to recover
 the inequality that produced these pictures,
 from equipment more than 20 years bygone.
 Don’t make me cough up something new.)

This recipe might require more than 10 ingredients,
or just the same two or three ingredients over and again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a graph of

> $\operatorname{sign}(-\cot x y +\cot y - \tan x + 2)$

[image]

Comment: You dog! Thank you for finding a more direct route than the original! Ain't mathematics simply beautiful?!?!

Comment: [How did you know!?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAxzl.jpg)

Comment: Just a lucky guess! (For me, not you, you're a lucky find. So grateful . . .)